# error when uploading with Git

Tags: windows, git, cygwin, github

I am new to Git hub and was able to successfully create an ssh key and upload it to the website however when I type in

git push origin master

I receive the following error:

```
error: cannot run ssh: no such file or directory
fatal: unable to fork
```

I am using Cygwin on a windows Vista machine if that is also useful. Ok.. after installing openssh I now get the error:

```
Permission denied (publickey)
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to install openssh as well. Please re-run the cygwin setup and check openssh

Comment: ok.. now I get: Permission denied (publickey) fatal the remote end hung up unexpectedly

Answer (score 3):

You do not have ssh installed within Cygwin, or it's not in your path.  Make sure that you are able to run `ssh --version` successfully from the Cygwin prompt.

---

For the second error, this indicates that the key your ssh client is attempting to authenticate with is not trusted by the remote server.  Verify that the public key has been successfully added to your Github profile, and also verify that the public key you've added corresponds to the private key you are attempting to use.

Comment: ok.. now I get: Permission denied (publickey) fatal the remote end hung up unexpectedly